# Group Hours in R

Tags: r

Want to group the Hours in a data in R. I am getting output like this

```
1  2  3  4  5  6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24
```

but i want my output like

```
T1 T2 T3 T4 T5.
```

Where:

```
T1 = 1-5
T2 = 6-10
T3 = 11-15
T4 = 16-20
T5 = 21-24
```

Comment: See the 'ifelse' or 'cut' functions

Comment: if (crime_tree$Hour[crime_tree$Hour >=1 & crime_tree$Hour <=5]){
  crime_tree$Hour <- "T1"
}else if(crime_tree$Hour[crime_tree$Hour >=6 & crime_tree$Hour <= 10]){
  crime_tree$Hour <-"T2"
}else if(crime_tree$Hour[crime_tree$Hour >=11 & crime_tree$Hour <= 15]){
  crime_tree$Hour <-"T3"
}else if(crime_tree$Hour[crime_tree$Hour >= 16 & crime_tree$Hour <= 20]){
  crime_tree$Hour <-"T4"
}else
  crime_tree$Hour <-"T5"

Comment: Its not working

Comment: You are using an `if` statement, which is different (and not as useful in your case) from the `ifelse` function. have you looked at `?ifelse`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use a nested `ifelse` statement or a well-phrased call to `cut` to complete your task. Considering your question and your comments, I think it would be very helpful to read about the [`ifelse`](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/ifelse.html) and [`cut`](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/cut.html) functions.

#### Use `ifelse`

```
hrs <- 1:24
ifelse(hrs <= 5, '1-5', 
       ifelse(hrs <= 10, '6-10', 
              ifelse(hrs <= 15, '11-15', 
                     ifelse(hrs <= 20, '16-20', '21-24'))))
```

#### Use `cut`

```
cut(x = hrs,
    breaks = c(1, 5, 10, 15, 20, 24), 
    include.lowest = TRUE,
    labels = paste0(c(1,6,11,16,21), '-', c(5,10,15,20,24)))
```